# Wordpress media uploader not uploading properly

Tags: wordpress, media, uploader

I am uploading media via the Wordpress media uploader. It says it uploads the file fine (and if I check inside my uploads folder, it is in fact there).

But the image is broken on the frontend, and if I go to the media uploader, it shows a broken image. 
[image]
[image]

Now the strange thing, is if I click 'edit image' in the media uploader, it shows me the image...
[image]

the link to the image is also correct except when I use that link to view the image I am taken to a 404 page.

I would like to add that I de-activated all the plugins I am using and there is no change. As well, I've given the uploads folder permissions of 777. No change.

The uploader works fine on my remote server, but this happens when I use the site locally (using MAMP).

I just want to know what the problem is and if it is something that will occur when I set the site live on another server...What is going on?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check your server error log ?

Comment: Hmm, good idea. Be right back...

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary in the server logs..

Comment: Did you check your media size settings are correct ?

Comment: Yes, in fact I modified it to be a larger upload size, but just in case it was causing the problem I removed it from .htaccess. Still no change.

Comment: I added some screenshots up above to give you an idea of what is happening.

Comment: Found the problem. I had a .htaccess file in the uploads folder that was preventing it from working.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have any `.htaccess` or `php.ini` with restrictions for all SPECIFIC related folders ( `Content`, `Uploads` , `Year/Month` folders )

One of them is bound to exists .
Otherwise - it is a hosting problem / configuration .